# Search mySQL with PHP, using a WHERE wildcard or an IF statement?

Tags: php, sql, search, wildcard, if-statement

I'm letting users search my database for data by city.
My query looks like:

`$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mydb WHERE City='".$city."' LIMIT 10");`

I want a user to be able to search 'all cities', so I'd like to either remove the WHERE statement if $city=='all cities'; or use a wildcard for the WHERE statement that matches all cities in the db.

I used to have an IF statement that switched between two queries, but I want to add more filters like country/all countries, zipcode/all zipcodes, etc, So I'd rather keep one dynamic SQL query.

Comment: Obligatory warning about taking `$city` from user input: http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could still have just one query and build the where clause dynamically, as such:

```
$where = '';

// conditional statements (if/else, switch) for populating the where clause
$where .= " WHERE City = '{$city}'";
$where .= " AND Country = '{$country}'";

$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mydb{$where} LIMIT 10");
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be a case statement:

```
WHERE City = case when '$city' = 'All cities' then City else '$city' end
```

If the user is searching for 'All cities', this turns the WHERE statement into:

```
WHERE City = City
```

Which is always true (at least for non-null cities ;))

P.S. Make sure you're running these queries using a read-only MySQL account. The user could enter funny stuff into the `$city` parameter!

Comment: Regarding your last comment: To block funny stuff just use prepared statements or the proper escape functions. Of course, a read-only MySQL account can't hurt either.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
WHERE City like '$city'
```

and permit the users to enter wildcards, if you think they'd be up to it.

Answer (score 0):

although not PHP programmer, this pseudocode might offer an option... conditionally build out your where clause.  Additionally, I would do it with parameterized queries instead of direct string building to prevent sql-injection attacks.

```
cYourSQL = "select * from YourTable where "

cAndRequired = ""

if city is NOT "all cities"
  cYourSQL = cYourSQL + cAndRequired + " city = 'YourParameterValueProvided' "
  cAndRequired = " AND "
endif
```

Now, always add your country selection

```
cYourSQL = cYourSQL + cAndRequired + " country = 'YourCountryValue' LIMIT 10 "
```

Run the query